# Jest test cannot find module error when trying to mock react-native-device-info

Tags: react-native, jestjs

All my tests are failing when trying to mock react-native-device-info, any ideas?

testenv.js

```
jest.mock('react-native-device-info', () => {
    return {
        getModel: jest.fn(),
        getVersion: jest.fn(),
        getBuildNumber: jest.fn(),
        getBundleId: jest.fn(),
    };
});
```

Error:

```
Cannot find module 'react-native-device-info' from 'testenv.js'

   7 |         getVersion: jest.fn(),
   8 |         getBuildNumber: jest.fn(),
>  9 |         getBundleId: jest.fn(),
     |               ^
  10 |     };
  11 | });
  12 | require('jest-fetch-mock').enableMocks();

  at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:299:11)
  at Object.<anonymous> (testenv.js:9:15)
```